# How to transverse xml nodes using xslt to match values in form of where condition

Tags: xslt

The output below is expected. Given the xslt is sorted by SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR
The Output xml below

```
<ORDER_DATA_Main>
   <ORDER_DATA>
      <SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>97915</SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>
         <MASTER_P>0001</MASTER_P>
   </ORDER_DATA>
   <ORDER_DATA>
      <SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>97916</SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>
      <MASTER_P>0002</MASTER_P>
    </ORDER_DATA>
    <ORDER_DATA>
      <SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>97917</SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>
      <MASTER_P>0003</MASTER_P>
   </ORDER_DATA>
</ORDER_DATA_Main>
```

xml file

```
<ORDER_DATA>
   <ORDER_P>
      <ORDER_QUANTITY>
         <SKU_INFO>
            <TQTY>260</TQTY>
         </SKU_INFO>
      <SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO_HEADER>
         <SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO>
            <CONTRYOFORIGIN>US</CONTRYOFORIGIN>
            <SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>97916</SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>
         </SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO>
         <MASTER_PALETTE>
            <MASTER_P>0002</MASTER_P>
         </MASTER_PALETTE>
      </SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO_HEADER>
   </ORDER_QUANTITY>
</ORDER_P>
   <ORDER_P>
      <ORDER_QUANTITY>
         <SKU_INFO>
            <TQTY>250</TQTY>
          </SKU_INFO>
      <SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO_HEADER>
         <SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO>
             <CONTRYOFORIGIN>US</CONTRYOFORIGIN>
             <SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>97915</SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR>
         </SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO>
         <MASTER_PALETTE>
            <MASTER_P>0001</MASTER_P>
          </MASTER_PALETTE>
         </SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO_HEADER>
      </ORDER_QUANTITY>
    </ORDER_P>
</ORDER_DATA>
```

below xslt snippet
xsltsnippet
xsltcode

```
<MASTER_P>
<xsl:value-of select="//MASTER_PALETTE[//SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO/SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR=$v_pallett]/MASTER_P"/>
</MASTER_P>
```

Comment: Where is the XSLT snippet and where is the desired output corresponding to this input? Anyway, it would be better to provide a minimal reproducible example, with enough XSLT code that can run as standalone, in order to let us run the code locally.

Comment: And indenting the XML input would help us to see better the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MASTER_PALETTE` and `SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO` are siblings. When you write

```
select="//MASTER_PALETTE[//SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO...]
```

the `//` within the predicate means the predicate will be true if any `SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO` anywhere in the document satisfies the conditions, regardless whether it is related in any way to the `MASTER_PALETTE` being tested. Instead of `//` here, try `../`.

Comment: Hi @Michael  . Thanks for the input. Is there any link or post.. where I could understand the application of  // or ../ within an XSLT document. ?   What I understood is select="//MASTER_PALETTE[../SHIPPED_GOODS_INFO/SHIPPEDQTYPALLETNR=$v_pallett]

Comment: There are lots of XPath tutorials around, but actually the W3C spec is quite readable, and if you want something that tries to offer more explanations and examples than the spec, I would recommend my book ;-)